# Javafx ScrollPane can't change background

Tags: java, javafx

I tried using:

`scrollPane.setStyle(".scroll-pane > .viewport  { -fx-background-color: red; }");`

but it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing this css thing wrong.

Comment: The style can’t have a selector, only CSS rules.  In other words, `setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;")` would be valid (though it probably wouldn’t achieve the effect you’re seeking).  You can, however, do a [lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) to get the viewport from a CSS selector.

Comment: Ok, tought so about setStyle method. Now I'm interested in the lookup thing but what would I put as an argument because I do not know what would be the id of the viewport?

Comment: The lookup method takes a CSS selector—the part before the braces-enclosed rule set.  In this case, `".viewport"` is probably sufficient.

Comment: Tried that one instantly, but it returned null each time.

Comment: The ScrollPane doesn’t have its structure until the Stage is realized.  Try `stage.setOnShown(e -> scrollPane.lookup(".viewport").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"));`.  Or, of course, you can specify everything in a separate stylesheet and add it to the Scene’s list of stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if you want put your comment in the answer section so I can mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Node’s style can’t have a selector, only CSS rules. In other words, setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;") would be valid (though it probably wouldn’t achieve the effect you’re seeking).

You can, however, do a [lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) to get the viewport from a CSS selector.

The ScrollPane doesn’t have its structure until the Stage is realized. The `.viewport` descendant will be there once the stage is shown:

```
stage.setOnShown(e ->
    scrollPane.lookup(".viewport").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"));
```

Alternatively, you can specify your original selector and rules in a separate stylesheet:

```
.scroll-pane > .viewport  { -fx-background-color: red; }
```

and then add it to the Scene’s list of stylesheets:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
    getClass().getResource("styles.css").toString());
```

Comment: Thanks @VGR. The alternative you mentioned above also works with FXML files.

Answer (score -2):

ScrollPane has an AnchorPane as his child. You have to set this particular AnchorPane's background color.

Comment: The viewport is a stackpane, not an anchorpane. To be a valid question, you should actually show how to do this - it is by no means obvious from what you have written.

Comment: @James_D You're right - I'll take your advice in the future. It's O.K. you set my answer as "not useful"... I just tried to help my brother, but I did not have enough of time. I hope, it will never happen again. Cheers.